# How to solve certain equations with unknown in the Gaussian integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find z in the Gaussian integers in the following 3 equations ?

1. |z|+Rez=1

my idea:

|z|+(z-Imz)=1

2z-Imz=1

2z^2-Imz^2=1

2z^2-y^2=1

2z^2=1-y^2

hmm i dont know how to continue

2. z=3-i+5e^it, 0 ≤ t ≤ π
3. z=te^it, t≥0

I dont have an idea for 2 and 3, but i'm sure that I have to use the equation $z=r \cdot e^{i \varphi}$.

Comment: Start with z = K + Li, where K and L are integers and i is the imaginary unit. That is what it means to say that z is a Gaussian integer. Then rewrite equation 1. in terms of K and L.

Comment: is the solution x≤1/2? can you help me now with 2. and 3.?

Answer (score 1):

Assume: $z=x+iy$

Then $|z|+\text{Re}z=1 \implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x=1$.

We can reformulate this to $x^2+y^2=(1-x)^2\implies x^2+y^2 = 1-2x+x^2\implies y^2=1-2x$

If we solve the last equation for $x$ we obtain

$$x=0.5-0.5y^2,$$

which is a parabola in the complex plane.

If you plug $y^2=1-2x$ into the second equation you will get

$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}+x=1\implies |x-1|+x=1$. Assuming $x \geq 1$ you will obtain $2x=2 \implies x=1$(not a valid solution). The $x < 1$ case will lead to $-(x-1)+x=1$, which is true. Hence, the domain for the parabola is $x<1$.

Comment: thank you. can you help me with 2. and 3. too?